Wordle game clone having type errors string can't be used to index type {}, and map does not exist on type never
EDIT: Full error
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{}'.
No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{}'.ts(7053)
I was following a guide to making a wordle clone in react. I was trying to create it in typescript but am running into lots of typing issues some of which I was able to solve. One I am stuck on is "Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{}'" For the keyboard keys. (PrevUsedKeys below). I found online that a way to fix this is to declare it a isKeyOf but I could not get that working with interfaces or without.
Does anyone know how I would type this so as to fix the error. Preferably strictly typed but I'd even be open to how to make it  enough that it allows me to build.
Then in a separate KeyPad component I am getting map does not exist on type never. Based on what I saw online I tried const [letters, setLetters] = useState<any[]>([null]); But that completely broke the program, whereas with just (null) it works but has typing errors.
Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.
Bonus Question if anyone looks at the github: I also have a component that takes in props and generates a react bootstrap Toast that self closes, telling the user if they attempted to use the same word twice, or are attempting to submit something that is not a word.  Right now it works and displays as it should, but it only displays once and never again. I have used this component before without this issue but have never tried using it inside a custom hook. I assume somewhere it is keeping the state for showModal always true or always false, but I can't seem to get it working.
interface LetterInfo {
key: string,
color: string,
}

const useWordGame = (secretWord: string | null[]) => {

    const [turn, setTurn] = useState(0);
    const [currentGuess, setCurrentGuess] = useState("");
    const [guesses, setGuesses] = useState([...Array(6)]); // each guess is an array
    const [history, setHistory] = useState([""]); // each guess is a string
    const [isCorrect, setIsCorrect] = useState(false);
    const [usedKeys, setUsedKeys] = useState({});
    const [notificationText, setNotificationText] = useState("");
    const [showNotification, setShowNotification] = useState(false);

    // format a guess into an array of letter objects 
    // e.g. [{key: 'a', color: 'yellow'}]
    const formatGuess = () => {
        let secretWordArray = [...secretWord];
        let formattedGuess = [...currentGuess].map((l) => {
            return { key: l, color: 'grey' };
        });

        // find any green letters
        formattedGuess.forEach((l, i) => {
            if (secretWord[i] === l.key) {
                formattedGuess[i].color = 'green';
                secretWordArray[i] = null;
            }
        });

        // find any yellow letters
        formattedGuess.forEach((l, i) => {
            if (secretWordArray.includes(l.key) && l.color !== 'green') {
                formattedGuess[i].color = 'yellow';
                secretWordArray[secretWordArray.indexOf(l.key)] = null;
            }
        });

        return formattedGuess;
    }

    const addNewGuess = (formattedGuess: Array<LetterInfo>) => {
        if (currentGuess === secretWord) {
            setIsCorrect(true);
        }
        setGuesses(prevGuesses => {
            let newGuesses = [...prevGuesses];
            newGuesses[turn] = formattedGuess;
            return newGuesses;
        })
        setHistory(prevHistory => {
            return [...prevHistory, currentGuess];
        })
        setTurn(prevTurn => {
            return prevTurn + 1;
        })
        setUsedKeys(prevUsedKeys => {
            formattedGuess.map(l => {
                const currentColor: Array<LetterInfo> = prevUsedKeys[l.key];

                if (l.color === 'green') {
                    prevUsedKeys[l.key] = 'green';
                    return;
                }
                if (l.color === 'yellow' && currentColor !== 'green') {
                    prevUsedKeys[l.key] = 'yellow';
                    return;
                }
                if (l.color === 'grey' && currentColor !== ('green' || 'yellow')) {
                    prevUsedKeys[l.key] = 'grey';
                    return;
                }
            })

            return prevUsedKeys;
        })
        setCurrentGuess("");

    }


    export default function Keypad({ keys, usedKeys }: any) {
  const [letters, setLetters] = useState(null);
//   const [letters, setLetters] = useState<any[]>([null]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setLetters(keys)
  }, [keys])

  return (
    <div className="keypad">
      {letters && letters.map(l => {
        const color = usedKeys[l.key]
        return (
          <div key={l.key} className={color}>{l.key}</div>
        )
      })}
    </div>
  )
}

For more of the code the repo is:
https://github.com/markdrecoll/word_game
In another post I saw it suggested to have const temp = someObj[field as keyof typeof someObj]
However if I try using that in my case with prevUsedKeys[l.key as keyof prevUsedKeys] it does not work.

but I could not get that working This is not a question.  What is your actual question here?  This website works best when you ask a specific question.

Sorry. How to resolve the "Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{}'" Error. And the map does not exist on type never. Since these are preventing me from building.

Please post the full error message, so we don't have to guess exactly where the error happens.

Sorry, just posted full error. It occurs in every location that has prevUsedKeys[l.key].

Switching usedKeys to an Array instead of an Object seemed to help. Then I can do const currentColor: any = prevUsedKeys[l.key as keyof typeof prevUsedKeys]; with no error.
But then on the lower three where it sets the color property of PrevUsedKeys I get this error: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because index expression is not of type 'number'.ts(7015)
